# update Trigger - Mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, trigger

tengo que crear un trigger asociado a la tabla pedidos de manera que cuando se actualice un registro de la tabla pedidos lo actualice en la tabla detallepedidos, lo he intentado de la siguiente forma pero no hay manera, si alguien lo pudiera resolver....

```
drop table if exists updatepedidos; 
create table updatepedidos (
  CodigoPedido integer NOT NULL,
  FechaPedido date NOT NULL,
  FechaEsperada date NOT NULL,
  FechaEntrega date DEFAULT NULL,
  Estado varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  Comentarios text,
  CodigoCliente integer NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CodigoPedido),
  CONSTRAINT Pedidos_Cliente FOREIGN KEY (CodigoCliente) REFERENCES Clientes (CodigoCliente)
);


drop trigger if exists controlpedidos; 

DELIMITER //

create trigger controlpedidos before update on pedidos for each row 
begin

if new.CodigoPedido<>old.CodigoPedido then 
insert into updatepedidos values (new.CodigoPedido, old.FechaPedido, old.FechaEsperada, old.FechaEntrega, old.Estado, old.Comentarios, old.CodigoCliente);
end if;

if new.FechaPedido<>old.FechaPedido then 
insert into updatepedidos values (old.CodigoPedido, new.FechaPedido, old.FechaEsperada, old.FechaEntrega, old.Estado, old.Comentarios, old.CodigoCliente);
end if;

if new.FechaEsperada<>old.FechaEsperada then 
insert into updatepedidos values (old.CodigoPedido, old.FechaPedido, new.FechaEsperada, old.FechaEntrega, old.Estado, old.Comentarios, old.CodigoCliente);
end if;

if new.FechaEntrega<>old.FechaEntrega then 
insert into updatepedidos values (old.CodigoPedido, old.FechaPedido, old.FechaEsperada, new.FechaEntrega, old.Estado, old.Comentarios, old.CodigoCliente);
end if;

if new.Estado<>old.Estado then 
insert into updatepedidos values (old.CodigoPedido, old.FechaPedido, old.FechaEsperada, old.FechaEntrega, new.Estado, old.Comentarios, old.CodigoCliente);
end if;

if new.Comentarios<>old.Comentarios then 
insert into updatepedidos values (old.CodigoPedido, old.FechaPedido, old.FechaEsperada, old.FechaEntrega, old.Estado, new.Comentarios, old.CodigoCliente);
end if;

if new.CodigoCliente<>old.CodigoCliente then 
insert into updatepedidos values (old.CodigoPedido, new.FechaPedido, old.FechaEsperada, old.FechaEntrega, old.Estado, old.Comentarios, new.CodigoCliente);
end if;

end//
DELIMITER ;

update pedidos set CodigoCliente=22 where CodigoPedido=1;
```

Comment: Tu update afecta algun registro cuando lo ejecutas? mysql te retorna one row afected o algo parecido?

Answer (score 1):

Estas insertando no haces ningún UPDATE en el disparador, imagino que usas IF para saber si existe el registro o no en la tabla updatepedidos.

Otro detalle es que no puedes hacer un update con `CodigoPedido` porque es un PK. (en realidad te permite pero no es una buena practica)

Lo que tendrías que hacer es con el código `CodigoPedido` buscar si existe datos registro en tu tabla `updatepedidos`, si es null usas insert sino update filtrando con el `CodigoPedido`.

Ejecuta `describe pedidos;` para saber que datos contiene la tabla.